# XeLaTeX and 10x20 font

Tags: fonts, xetex

In Emacs I use the 10x20 font because it has a great support for
Unicode symbols. I tried to use this font with `xelatex` using
something like

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{10x20}

\begin{document}
\texttt{Testing the mono font.}
\end{document}
```

but I got the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "10x20" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I know I should use the font name with `\setmonofont`, but the
only information I have is that 10x20 is a short name for
-Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--20-200-75-75-C-100-ISO10646-1.

Can I use the 10x20 font with `xelatex`?

Comment: This looks like an X bitmap font, XeTeX does not support bitmap fonts (apart from MetaFont bitmaps).

Comment: without some sort of conversion, i don't think there's a chance of using the font with xetex.  (i did a bit of a search, and all fonts i found, whose name includes "10x20", are x11 bitmap fonts ... which would seem to confirm khaled hosny's hypothesis.)

Comment: Thanks. I will see if I can use some sort of conversion for using the font.

Comment: @AndrésSicard-Ramírez You may try FreeMono that has a wide coverage of Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The 10x20 font is almost surely a bitmap font that can be used with X11 displays, but not with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX that require OpenType or TrueType fonts.

For a monospaced font with wide coverage of Unicode, you can try FreeMono, that's included in TeX Live.